# No implementation found for int io.netty.internal.tcnative.Library.aprMajorVersion()

Tags: android-studio, google-api-client

I have been trying to implement Google's Natural Language API. When I go to validate my credentials it's having a problem with netty. Any clue on how to solve this? I'm using Java8 btw. I saw on some other threads that it was a Java version that was this issue.

````
    String text = "My name is Teneala. I ran last week.";
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credentials);
    try {
        GoogleCredential credential = null;
        credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(is);

        Collection<String> scopes = Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-language");

        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            credential = credential.createScoped(scopes);
        }

        // copy over key values, note the additional "s", set some expiry
        // com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials
        GoogleCredentials sac = ServiceAccountCredentials.newBuilder()
                .setPrivateKey(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
                .setPrivateKeyId(credential.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())
                .setClientEmail(credential.getServiceAccountId())
                .setScopes(scopes)
                .setAccessToken(new AccessToken(credential.getAccessToken(), null))
                .build();

        // Latest generation Google libs, GoogleCredentials extends Credentials
        CredentialsProvider cp = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(sac);
        LanguageServiceSettings settings = (LanguageServiceSettings) LanguageServiceSettings.newBuilder().setCredentialsProvider(cp).build();
        LanguageServiceClient language = LanguageServiceClient.create(settings);

        Document doc = Document.newBuilder()
                .setContent(text)
                .setType(Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
                .build();
        AnalyzeSyntaxRequest request = AnalyzeSyntaxRequest.newBuilder()
                .setDocument(doc)
                .setEncodingType(EncodingType.UTF16)
                .build();
        // analyze the syntax in the given text
        AnalyzeSyntaxResponse response = language.analyzeSyntax(request);
        // print the response
        for (Token token : response.getTokensList()) {
            System.out.printf("\tText: %s\n", token.getText().getContent());
            System.out.printf("\tBeginOffset: %d\n", token.getText().getBeginOffset());
            System.out.printf("Lemma: %s\n", token.getLemma());
            System.out.printf("PartOfSpeechTag: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getTag());
            System.out.printf("\tAspect: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getAspect());
            System.out.printf("\tCase: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getCase());
            System.out.printf("\tForm: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getForm());
            System.out.printf("\tGender: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getGender());
            System.out.printf("\tMood: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getMood());
            System.out.printf("\tNumber: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getNumber());
            System.out.printf("\tPerson: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getPerson());
            System.out.printf("\tProper: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getProper());
            System.out.printf("\tReciprocity: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getReciprocity());
            System.out.printf("\tTense: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getTense());
            System.out.printf("\tVoice: %s\n", token.getPartOfSpeech().getVoice());
            System.out.println("DependencyEdge");
            System.out.printf("\tHeadTokenIndex: %d\n", token.getDependencyEdge().getHeadTokenIndex());
            System.out.printf("\tLabel: %s\n\n", token.getDependencyEdge().getLabel());
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```
````

Here is my gradle file. I've tried excluding it, I've looked into troubleshooting documentation, I've tried implementing it, ect.

```
    dependencies {
    // Google APIs
    implementation('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'org.google', module: 'google'
        exclude group: 'com.google.auto.value', module: 'auto-value'
        //exclude 'io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.20.Final:'
    }
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:1.12.0'
    implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.14.0'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.auto.value', module: 'auto-value'
        //exclude 'io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.20.Final:'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the solution here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#troubleshooting. I had to add this to the app build gradle. Something about netty not being support on Android Devices.

```
implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.7.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
```